# Unable to run websphere application server docker image

Tags: linux, docker, websphere

I have pulled the docker image from `docker pull ibmcom/websphere-traditional` command.
 and execute below command to run websphere application server 
 
 `sudo docker run -it --name was145-server -h was145-server -e UPDATE_HOSTNAME=true -e PROFILE_NAME=AppSrv01 -e NODE_NAME=DefaultNode02 -e SERVER_NAME=server2 -p 9043:9043 -p 9443:9443 -v /scratch/wls-docker/obs-swedbank-was/data-files/opt/IBM/WebSphere/:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/ -d ibmcom/websphere-traditional:latest` 
 I am getting below errors

```
/work/applyConfig.sh: line 3: /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/bin/wsadmin.sh: No such file or directory
/work/start_server.sh: line 15: hostname: command not found
/work/start_server.sh: line 15: wsadmin.sh: command not found
HPEL is enabled
Starting logViewer ................
/work/start_server.sh: line 29: /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/bin/logViewer.sh: No such file or directory
Starting server ...................
/work/start_server.sh: line 22: /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/bin/startServer.sh: No such file or directory
Configure logging mode
/work/configure_logging.sh: line 4: /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/bin/wsadmin.sh: No such file or directory
/work/applyConfig.sh: line 3: /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/bin/wsadmin.sh: No such file or directory
HPEL is enabled
Starting logViewer ................
/work/start_server.sh: line 29: /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/bin/logViewer.sh: No such file or directory
Starting server ...................
/work/start_server.sh: line 22: /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/bin/startServer.sh: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue comes from the fact that you mapped `/opt/IBM/WebSphere/` to the host folder `/scratch/wls-docker/obs-swedbank-was/data-files/opt/IBM/WebSphere/', which I suppose it is empty!

When the container starts, it tries to run `/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/bin/wsadmin.sh` searching for it into the physical path `/scratch/wls-docker/obs-swedbank-was/data-files/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/bin/wsadmin.sh`, but it does not find it.

Is it true for you what I stated?

I don't know exactly what that folder contains, but I suggest you to map to externals folder only the `/opt/IBM/WebSphere/` subfolders you need, leaving the binary components as they are inside the container.

Comment: Yes exactly, i think these shell files should be copy in respected paths, as i have checked in DockerFile, as other folders its creating

Comment: But i am sorry, i have not got any solution, you have technically explained the issue, but what should i do to resolve this ?

Comment: I edited the post with more information and a suggestione for you.

Comment: If it suites for you, please accept the answer.

Comment: /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/bin/logViewer.sh this shell file is not include in source code also.

Comment: The short answer is "delete the `-v ...:/opt/IBM/WebSphere` option"; what host files do you expect to be there?